# How to do major compaction on a transactional table in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a transactional table and I want to create the dataframe on this transactional table using Major compaction. But I don't know how to do it.
So, can anyone tell me the steps to do Major compaction on a transactional table?

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you're having an issue with.

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to do. ? compaction is abstract activity which doesnt affect any functionality.

Comment: Since my table is transactional, so we cann't directly use spark to create dataframe. There are 2 ways to create dataframe on transactional table. One is by using JDBC and the other is Major compaction. @ShivaKumarSS

Answer (score 1):

You may have conflated `hbase` with `hive`/`spark`: there is no concern of `compaction` (let alone "major" compaction) on the latter.

Comment: Since my table is transactional, so we cann't directly use spark to create dataframe. There are 2 ways to create dataframe on transactional table. One is by using JDBC and the other is Major compaction. @javadba

Comment: What are you talking about *using major compaction to create dataframe on transactional table* . That is not a spark concept or capability

Comment: It is not `hive` but `hbase` - as mentioned above  http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.com/2014/07/about-hbase-flushes-and-compactions.html